# compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'loss'

Tags: python, keras

I see the above error when executing the code below to add a custom loss function.

```py
   mymodel.add_loss(custom_loss)
   mymodel.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

error: compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'loss'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_model.compile(loss=my_custom_loss_function(), optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 0):

see : https://github.com/llSourcell/autoencoder_explained/issues/1

change the code to

```py
   mymodel.add_loss(custom_loss)
   mymodel.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='')
```